# Comparing two documents and writing output to a third [Python?]

Tags: python, sql, database, hash

I am seeking some advice whether it be in terms of a script (possibly python?) that I could use to do the following.

I basically have two documents, taken from a DB:

**document one contains :**

```
hash / related username.
```

example:

```
fb4aa888c283428482370   username1
fb4aa888c283328862370   username2
fb4aa888c283422482370   username3
fb4aa885djsjsfjsdf370   username4
fb4aa888c283466662370   username5
```

**document two contains:**

```
hash : plaintext
```

example:

```
fb4aa888c283428482370:plaintext
fb4aa888c283328862370:plaintext2
fb4aa888c283422482370:plaintext4
fb4aa885djsjsfjsdf370:plaintextetc
fb4aa888c283466662370:plaintextetc
```

can anyone think of an easy way for me to match up the hashes in document two with the relevant username from document one into a new document (say document three) and add the plain so it would look like the following...

```
Hash : Relevant Username : plaintext
```

This would save me a lot of time having to cross reference two files, find the relevant hash manually and the user it belongs to.
I've never actually used python before, so some examples would be great!

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is customary that if you were given an answer to your question, you mark it as such....or follow up to get the answer that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any code for you but a very basic way to do this would be to whip up a script that does the following:

1. Read the first doc into a dictionary with the hashes as keys.
2. Read the second doc into a dictionary with the hashes as keys.
3. Iterate through both dictionaries, by key, in the same loop, writing out the info you want into the third doc.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really specify how you wanted the output, but this should get you close enough to modify to your liking. There are guys out there good enough to shorten this into a fey lines of code - but I think the readability of keeping it long may be helpful to you just getting started.

Btw, I would probably avoid this altogether and to the join in SQL before creating the file -- but that wasn't really your question : )

```
usernames = dict()
plaintext = dict()
result = dict()

with open('username.txt') as un:
    for line in un:
        arry = line.split() #Turns the line into an array of two parts
        hash, user = arry[0], arry[1]
        usernames[hash] = user.rsplit()[0] # add to dictionary

with open('plaintext.txt') as un:
    for line in un:
        arry = line.split(':')
        hash, txt = arry[0], arry[1]
        plaintext[hash] = txt.rsplit()[0]

for key, val in usernames.items():
    hash = key
    txt = plaintext[hash]
    result[val] = txt

with open("dict.txt", "w") as w:
    for name, txt in result.items():
        w.write('{0} = {1}\n'.format(name, txt))

print(usernames)  #{'fb4aa888c283466662370': 'username5', 'fb4aa888c283422482370': 'username3' ...................
print(plaintext) #{'fb4aa888c283466662370': 'plaintextetc', 'fb4aa888c283422482370': 'plaintext4' ................
print(result) #{'username1': 'plaintext', 'username3': 'plaintext4', .....................
```